# Notarize DMG fail due to the binary is not signed and he signature does not include a secure timestamp

Tags: macos

By running command --notarization-info. we have got below logs : 
https://osxapps-ssl.itunes.apple.com/itunes-assets/Enigma114/v4/aa/c9/4a/aac94a15-bc98-a573-02fc-4bded9af1d5c/developer_log.json?accessKey=1583334369_3018794451668908723_%2FNR0bVue2BJsfcri1LwUBYYNUNAgh9YvPsY080fkL8DqcqJira1V7IpIROD2D6GvFusU%2Bz2cVs6grF1brF0x88hksLTJF68DZA9N%2Bx6WlyfX7CriS3MoYgzYKDuXKo%2FCfW3yQbCf9wHdQWjswhxd%2F37bUNGvEH%2FEs98fIQvndYQ%3D

If we remove ffmpegsumo.so file from .app file. DMG got approved with status code 0. But its not running on the system.
file path:   eTGComplete.app/Contents/Frameworks/nwjs\ Framework.framework/Libraries/ffmpegsumo.so

Comment: You will need a signed version of ffmpegsumo.so or sign it. Your app won't get notarized until you have a signed ffmpegsumo.so.

Comment: I have tried to sign single file ffmpegsumo.so but still getting same issue.

Comment: My issue got solved after doing following steps - 

1) codesign -f -v -s "Developer ID Application: XXYY, Inc. (XXYY)" --force --timestamp --options runtime --preserve-metadata=entitlements --verbose=4 --deep /Users/sampleUser/Documents/REPO/MyApplication.app/Contents/Frameworks/Sparkle.framework/Resources/Autoupdate.app


2) codesign -s "Developer ID Application: XXYY, Inc. (XXYY)" --force --options runtime --preserve-metadata=entitlements --verbose=4 --deep /Users/sampleUser/Documents/REPO/MyApplication.app


NOTE: Here both steps should have SAME Developer ID Application